# Export files from image data type in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I export my attachments from image data type in sql server 2008 without using xp_cmdshell? , I have researched myself and found solutions with xp_cmdhell or SSIS or .net or something, isn't there any way to just do it from sql server alone?

have done exports from BLOB datatype in oracle easliy , is it not possible in sql server 2008?

Please help

Comment: No one has a clue about this ??

Comment: Can someone please help me with this ?